# Does the underlying data binding of ReactiveUI in WPF use the native implementation of WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, reactiveui

Recently I am using `ReactiveUI` to make a `WPF` program. I am curious. When I use ReactiveUI for data binding, such as binding the string property of `ViewModel` to a `TextBox.Text`, does it use the native implementation of WPF to achieve binding? In fact, I’m not very familiar with the two, so I want to know the relationship between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't use the Binding class from WPF binding engine.

Instead it subscribes to the INotifyPropertyChanged, IReactiveObject, and DependencyProperty subscriptions directly and then will update the view/view model properties directly.

It has a concept of a `ICreatesObservable` class internally which describes how to get an observable for a property. These observables are triggered when the property is changed/changing. So for instance on WPF you'll have a `ICreatesObservable` for DependencyObject/DependencyProperty classes. It'll then combine these observables together to achieve the binding.

Comment: why it still need `DependencyProperty` or `INotifyPropertyChanged`, is WPF must depend on them?

Comment: Yeah, you need some mechanism to detect if a property has changed, those two are one the ones available in WPF.